# How to mongodump directly to a remote server?

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongodump

I don't have enough space to dump my MongoDB to a local server. So I got another machine which I mounted to my MongoDB machine as '/mnt/backup/' by using curlftpfs.

However, when I run:

```
sudo mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db DBNAME--authenticationDatabase admin --username USERNAME --password PSW --gzip --archive=/mnt/backup/archive.gz
```

I get an error:
**Failed: open /mnt/backup/archive.gz: operation not supported**

It doesn't look to be permission-related, because I can create and copy files to this location. It's something with an inability to run mongodump to an open remote file.

If I run the same command to my local folder, it works, but as I mentioned, there is not enough space to store the entire archive backup even when I use compression.

Is there any way to do this? Any suggestions would be welcome because as of now, I am effectively unable to backup my database.

Comment: If your database has many collections, then running mongodump for each collection individually could be a pitch?

Comment: And how about running the command `mongodump` on another machine that has enough space? You will need to change the `host` parameter in this case.

Comment: I thought of that, but there is an issue, it's really a cloud backup server from rsync.net that doesn't allow to be logged into.

Comment: Try using standard out and redirecting the output, like `--archive > /mnt/backup/archive.gz`

Comment: @Joe, that was a good idea, but even when I run it as sudo, I am getting: -bash: /mnt/backup/archive.gz: Permission denied

Comment: That would imply the problem is with your account's ability to write to the device, not with the program generating the file data.